# Making canvas visible out of canvas

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

Is it possible to render canvas element out of own area?

In this example I draw a rectangle, which x-coordinate and y-coordinate is a negative value. Is it possible to render whole rectangle? `overflow` rule doesn't work here.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3m8he2j/)

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col main">
      <canvas id="example" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("example");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(-30, -30, 150, 100);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();
```

css

```
.row {
  background: CornflowerBlue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main, canvas {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: This is not possible. Think of a canvas an interactive image, it's just one element with it's set boundaries, everything inside it is a part of it (rather than a contained element that may be able to break the boundaries) However using a larger canvas and faking the "edge" of the canvas is a possible workaround.

Comment: Maybe you should explain why do you need it for. Depending on the situation there may be some workarounds.